# Read memory from process dump (automatic analysis)

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll, dump

I need to automatically analyse dump files from a process. If I have the process running, I can just check where a specifc dll is and work from there. But how can I get this working if I only have the dump? Read the whole file and... ? I am somehow out of ideas currently... I think what I need would be a way to map the dump as process(?).  Maybe somebody here has an idea.

(if important, dmp is created from task manager, but that shouldn't matter I think).

Greetings

Comment: Use windbg (or CDB) to analyse dump files: https://www.wintellect.com/automating-analyzing-tons-of-minidump-files-with-windbg-and-powershell/

Comment: Start from [MiniDumpReadDumpStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpreaddumpstream).